# Brightness control on multiple monitors in Windows 10 via software (non DDC)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, lcd, brightness

I have three displays on a Windows 10 system that need to have brightness of the displays controlled individually.  Integrated LCD brightness controll is not sufficient; I must have additional software level brightness control at the OS level.

How can this be done when Display Settings does not have a brightness option to control brightness of displays?

Is there another option that will allow individually setting brightness of displays from the command line, a third party app or some other way?

Ideally it would be nice to find an app that would be able to work similar to [Shady](http://instinctivecode.com/shady/) on macOS (OS X) or [Brightness Controller](https://github.com/lordamit/Brightness) for Linux, which is even better as it easily controls all displays:

[image: Brightness Controller]

Answer (score 0):

If each monitor is connected to the PC directly, this can be done with [DDC protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel). There are programs you can use with this protocol to provide control.

Comment: The seeming problem with DDC is that: 1) this controls the hardware directly (not a software driven solution), and 2) LCD darkness is not able to bring the brightness level down low enough in this scenario.

Comment: I actually have had that same problem. If all you want to do is dim it further, there is a program called "Dimmer". http://www.nelsonpires.com/software/dimmer/ It's a little buggy on Windows 10, but it works. I don't think you can control each monitor separately though. There is another program called Flux to change color temperature based on time of day.

Comment: right, I have used a program similar to that that won't dim multiple displays.  Also I use f.lux on my Macs, Linux and Windows systems, but this doesn't do enough in the way of dimming the display(s).